How to use the Unix to set a multiline string export to use in a node js application
I have a script which I created to export a number of system or environment variables. I want to able to set variable which runs over many lines. Here is a portion of my file called env-variables.sh. The variable I want to set is a certificate in my environment
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
ebHRoUGFydG5lcnMxGjAYBgNVBAsTEUVudGVycHJpc2VTdG9yYWdlMSswKQYDVQQ
.....rest of file

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

export PORT_NUM=9077
export HOST_NM='medina-serv-dev.com'
export HOST_CERT= ... // want read place a cert value


Can someone show me how I can use a simple unix script to accomplish this? I want to get the value and load it using process.env in a node js app. Can the script read the file from the file system? If so how can I read the certificate file in a unix script

I think maybe you want HOST_CERT="$(</path/to/certificateFile)". If you need to remove ------BEGIN... and -----END... then HOST_CERT="$( sed '/^---/d' /path/to/certifcateFile)" If PORT_NUM and HOST_NM are important, then add a printf "%s%s%s" $PORT_NUM $HOST_NM $(sed ...)` wrapper like to the whole thing. (Post a new question and add a tag for your specific shell if you're still having trouble). Good luck.
